# why does the browser keeps throwing a cannot get message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a project using node js and express. When I try to execute the code i get a cannot get error in the browser. I fixed some mistakes. Now it looks like it is working because the terminal returned Express server started at port : 3000 and MongoDB Connection Succeeded.  but still getting the same message would you please help me?

```
  require('./models/db');

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const productController = require('./controllers/productController');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'mainLayout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Express server started at port : 3000');
});

app.use('/product', productController);
```

Thank you.

Comment: i'm following this tuto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voDummz1gO0

Comment: could you show us the code where you have the call to `listen()` in your express object?

Comment: @alexortizl sorry man I thought that what i posted

Comment: @sabrim Please check the answer as you need to browse http://localhost:3000/employee and for source code of the tutorial is https://github.com/CodAffection/Node.js-Expess-MongoDB-CRUD

Answer (score 0):

You need to browse the path in the browser as follows because on `http://localhost:3000` you are not returning anything.

```
http://localhost:3000/employee
```

Please check the following image which I run on my local machine.

[SOURCE CODE.](https://github.com/CodAffection/Node.js-Expess-MongoDB-CRUD)

[image]
Hope this will help you.